# Understanding css background shorthand properties

Tags: css, background

The shorthand definition of the css background property is as follows:

`background: color position/size repeat origin clip attachment image|initial|inherit;`

But then i find following examples:

```
body { 
  background: #00ff00 url('smiley.gif') no-repeat fixed center; 
}
```

So here the order is: color-image-repeat-attachment-position

Is there any reason why this order can change?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shorthand properties try not to force a specific order for the values of properties, this however works well when those properties have values of different types but not when those properties could have identical values.

Background shorthand property has values of different types so the order of values shouldn't cause errors, however you should stick to the standard order to maintain good readability.

Here's a manual from mozilla's dev center about shorthand properties, the statement that I quoted about the order can be seen under 'Tricky Edge Cases' at point #3.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Shorthand_properties